# Have any theologians speculated about the nature of Devas?

Tags: gods, philosophy, shad-darshana

Have any scholars throughout history done any in-depth thinking on the subject of what Devas (such as Indra, Surya, Agni) are? On their nature and mode of existence?

I'm not just looking for quotations of scripture, I'm asking if any scholars engaged in metaphysical speculation about devas that went beyond scripture.

Comment: It was heard somewhere that Mimamsa described the Devas to embody the inherent mystic powers of the Vaidika mantras which get activated mechanically if the Vaidika mantras are properly applied. Nyaya & Yoga are uninterested in the nature of Devas. Samkhya describes Devas as embodied beings endowed with supernatural powers born out of vikara of Purusha & Prakriti. Vedanta describes the Devas to be emanations of Brahman.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This is why we have terms like Nirguna Brahman which describe transcendental being. That is, it exists, but is indescribable.

Comment: I'm not talking about Brahman I'm talking about Devas like Indra, Surya, Agni.

Comment: The Devas come out of Brahman ...

Comment: And so does everything else. What have have scholars said about the nature of Devas, in particular?